Is it possbile to proxyPass all pages but exclude certain paths?
Currently I've got two systems which need to be ran under the same domain.
At the moment the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse works when targeting certain pages like:
<Location /payments>
     ProxyPass https://new-domain.com/payments
     ProxyPassReverse https://new-domain.co.uk/payments
     ProxyAddHeaders On
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     RequestHeader set host new-domain.com
</Location>

However if I want to use the new system as all the base pages, I've set it up to be the following:
<Location /blogs>
   ProxyPass !
</Location>

<Location />
   ProxyPass https://new-domain.co.uk/
   ProxyPassReverse https://new-domain.co.uk/
   ProxyAddHeaders On
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   RequestHeader set host new-domain.co.uk
</Location>

The blogs isn't being ignored and the new system code base is being picked up still. Is there a way to ignore the proxy for certain pages?
